# Fractions from provided numerator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with as_integer_ratio and i have fixed numerator as 1
so far
(0.1666666666).as_integer_ratio()
returns `(6016809102166983, 36028797018963968)`
but 1/6 is also return 0.1666666666
how can i get 1,6 as fractions?

Comment: This is not a realistic expectation, due to how to floating point numbers work. If you want to work with simple fractions, you should use the `fractions.Fraction` class from the standard library.

Comment: Could you please provide a "test-run" with input / output, so it is possible to understand what the desired behavior should be like? Just as a formatted code block / shell output if this is a cmd line app?